# UIButton rotate with CABasicAnimation does not move initial touch coordinates

Tags: ios, rotation

I have a UIView and i added a UIButton on it. I am rotating UIView by 180 degrees. After rotating UIView, everything inside it looks rotated including the button. But when i tap on button. it receives touch event only from its initial position. Not from the position it  appears on screen. This is my code -

```
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((180*M_PI)/180)];
fullRotation.speed = 1.0;
fullRotation.autoreverses = NO;
fullRotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
fullRotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[_subView.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from Interface Builder. You have to rotate it from your code. Like this,

```
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(selectedButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

    CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((180*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotation.speed = 1.0;
    fullRotation.autoreverses = NO;
    fullRotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    fullRotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [button.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Now the `selectedButton` will receive every rotated UIButton touch.